# UIView on UIWebView backgroundColor doesn't change

Tags: ios, uiview, uiwebview

I have a custom UIView subclass instance headerView, which I put on a scrollView of UIWebView. I set a background color of this view to white, when I init it:

```
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

This is how I put it on a scrollView of webView:

```
    webView.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(headerView.bounds.size.height, 0, 0, 0);

    CGRect frame = headerView.frame;
    frame.origin.y -= headerView.bounds.size.height;
    headerView.frame = frame;
    //webView.scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    [webView.scrollView addSubview:headerView];
```

If I uncomment the line, the background of my headerView is white. But if I comment it, the background color is the same as the background color of scrollView in webView. So, changing background color of a view in it's init method seems to not work.

Comment: What's the frame of your headerView when you add it to that scroll view? Messing with a `UIWebView`'s scroll view is not always safe

Another thing: It's not the same to change your headerView's background color than changing the scrollView's background color.

Comment: are you trying to get the headerView to showup? or just change the colors? (I am not sure what your goal is).

Comment: My goal is to make headerView's background white without changing background of webView's scrollView.

Comment: are you sure you're positioning the header view correctly?  Are the contents of the header view showing up?  It looks like the "y" you are setting to is off the edge and is getting clipped out..

Comment: In the commented line you are setting the background of the scroll view, not the headerview color. If you just want to check if the color of the view is changing just use '[webView.scrollView addSubview:headerView];' for adding the header view to the scrollview.

Comment: The true answer is below - frame was indeed incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a mistake that caused this problem. I was initing my view like this:

```
self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

And then setting frame:

```
frame = self.frame;
frame.size.height = _subjectView.bottom;
self.frame = frame;

self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.opaque = YES;
```

When I added this in init method:

```
self.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

The subviews didn't even show. So my superview's frame width was 0, but subviews still were showing outside it, since their frames were normal and clipsToBounds is NO by default. It was proved by adding this line

```
frame.size.width = SCREEN_WIDTH;
```

It started to work.

Answer (score 1):

In your subclass have you ensured that its opaque?

```
    self.view.opaque = YES;
```